# Kibana one vs all line graph

Tags: kibana

Suppose we have following data:

> Site:StackOverFlow, Date:24-09-18
>   Site:Google, Date:24-09-18
>   Site:Facebook, Date:24-09-18
>   Site:StackOverFlow, Date:23-09-18
>   Site:Twitter, Date:23-09-18
>   Site:Google, Date:22-09-18
>   Site:StackOverFlow, Date:21-09-18

I want to make a line graph in Kiabana with Count on y-axis, dates on x-axis and Two lines should be displayed, one will be count of stackoverflow, other will be count of rest sites.

I was able to create separate lines by adding `sub-buckets` and set dates by using `date-histogram aggregation`, but unable to do stackoverflow vs rest plotting.

Is it possible with kibana?